# bootstrap paging not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap paging is not working. I don't see page# in textbox in pager and it throws error to in jquery.tablesorter.pager.js function moveToFirstPage ln#33 which is table.config. table.config is unavailable.

Code looks like:

```
    <table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
         <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>val1</td>
            <td>val2</td>
                  </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
<div id="pager" class="pager" style="position:absolute;width:100%;background-color:#8F8F8F;color:White;">
        <form>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/first.png")" class="first"/>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/prev.png")" class="prev"/>
            <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" readonly="readonly" style="width:auto" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/next.png")" class="next"/>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/last.png")" class="last"/>
            Show <select class="pagesize" style="width:auto;">
                <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option  value="40">40</option>
            </select> items
        </form></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("table").tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });
```

what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big thing you are missing is making table itself table sorter. Just call `tablesorter` before `tablesorterPager` and there you go.

```
$("table").tablesorter().tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });
```

BTW, your table row and the pager option need to set properly.

Comment: yes, I was calling it before and was throwing config error on jquery.tablesorter.min.js

 $("table")
      .tablesorter({ }) 
      .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });

Comment: have you included the js file. what is the error? and which jquery version you are using?

Comment: it throws error at ln#539 in jquery.tablesorter.min.js. Error is "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.config.debug' is null or not an object" 

Jquery ver 1.8.3. could you provide more info on "your table row and the pager option need to set properly"?

Comment: I see error even changing code from $("table") .tablesorter({ }) to $("table") .tablesorter()

Comment: Update: I took tablesorter.js from here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html Mine ver was 2.7.3 (replaced by 2.0). Now I see error at ln#332 "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '0.length' is null or not an object"

Comment: All right, i have used your html as an example for you. I guess its the jquery issues. I am using jquery 1.7.2. Check this jsfiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/vDz88/

Comment: I'll expect a5his response as answer. I replaced tablesorter.js as in fiddler and it worked. I suspect tablesorter ver 2.7.3 has some issues.